# converting temp but the Fahrenheit value does not return

Tags: javascript

```
function CtoF(celsius, Fahrenheit) 
{
    Fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32; 
  console.log(celcius, "C is", Fahrenheit, "F");
  return Fahrenheit;
}
CtoF(celcius, Fahrenheit);
//3
function FtoC(celsius, Fahrenheit) 
{
    celcius = (Fahrenheit- 32) * 5 / 9;
  console.log(Fahrenheit, "F is", celcius, "c");
  return celcius;
}
FtoC(celcius,Fahrenheit);
```

First function works very fine but second doesnt cuz first function does not return Fahrenheit value at all.

I have a extra question.
I need to put "The larger number of 5 and 12 is 12." this sentence too but I dont know how I am gonna do it either inside or out side of function/ I know how to print out parameters inside of function but I dont know how to print out result in the function

```
function largerNum(num1,num2)
{
  if(num1>num2)
    return num1;
  else
    return num2;
}
console.log(largeNum(5,12));
```

Comment: You have got a random mixture of `celcius` and `celsius`. Fix these (the actual word is spelt "Celsius", for your info), and then see if anything else still needs fixing.

Comment: Why does the `CtoF` need a `Fahrenheit` parameter and vice versa?

Comment: cuz I have to change the value right after it, it's my school assignment.